# Applying sticky footer, can't set content Div height with header

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

This is so basic I'm embarrassed to post it up.

Basically anytime I add the banner inside of the wrap div, the main div will not keep it's height. I can't for the life of me get it to stretch to the footer. Taking the header out of the wrap tag didn't help either.

Searched thoroughly and came up with nothing! Sorry for such basic question

Original code is from http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testcss.css">
</head>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="header">
<img src="banner.png">
</div>
<div id="main">

</div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 /*  
Sticky Footer Solution
by Steve Hatcher 
http://stever.ca
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com
*/

* {margin:0;padding:0;} 

/* must declare 0 margins on everything, also for main layout components use padding, not 
vertical margins (top and bottom) to add spacing, else those margins get added to total height 
and your footer gets pushed down a bit more, creating vertical scroll bars in the browser */

html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #666;
    width: 100%;}
#header
{
    width: 800px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#main 
{   overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px; /* must be same height as the footer */
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 100%;}  

#footer
    {position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;
    background-color: #333;}
```